# Rhino Mocks LastCall syntax help, .NET

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, rhino-mocks

I have a problem understanding `LastCall()` method.

Below is an example:

```
public interface IDemo
{
     string Prop { get; set; }
     void VoidNoArgs();
}


[TestMethod]
public void SetupResultUsingOrdered()
{
     MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
     IDemo demo = mocks.StrictMock<IDemo>();

     SetupResult.For(demo.Prop).Return("Ayende");

     using(mocks.Ordered())
     {
          demo.VoidNoArgs();
          LastCall.On(demo).Repeat.Twice();
     }

     mocks.ReplayAll();

     demo.VoidNoArgs();

     for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
     {
          Assert.AreEqual("Ayende",demo.Prop);      
     }

     demo.VoidNoArgs();

     mocks.VerifyAll();
}
```

Am I right in saying:

`LastCall.On(demo).Repeat.Twice();` specifies that `demo.VoidNoArgs()`; is called twice and the last call.

However, there is a code block between `demo.VoidNoArgs()`. Does it mean that property is not counted when using `LastCall` method?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly ? You should not use Record/Replay syntax of RhinoMock as it's dead now. Try to learn with AAA (Arrange Act Assert) suntax instead

Comment: @Thoms, I don't agree with you. They coexist. http://ayende.com/wiki/Comparison+of+different+Rhino+Mocks+syntaxes.ashx

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. The above test passes on my machine. Do you want it to fail ? As in fail the test if property is invoked more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: Non-regular Rhino-mocks user.

SetupResult does not seem to be setting an expectation in this case. Since you're using a StrictMock, you need to be *explicit* in setting expectations on every call made on the mock.

If you want the test to

- check on only `two calls on VoidNoArgs and not anything else` : Comment the SetupResult line.
- check seq - `VoidNoArgs > Prop.get > VoidNoArgs`

.

```
using (mocks.Ordered())
{
        demo.VoidNoArgs();
        Expect.On(demo).Call(demo.Prop).Return("Ayende"); // fails unless you use .Repeat.Times(30) or make just one call.
        demo.VoidNoArgs();
```